# How do Facebook Server-to-server verify my App permissions

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-apps

I am developing a server-to-server Facebook App, that will require Features like Ads Management, Ads Read, Defaults, Pages Manage, Instagram, and a few others. But as my server-to-server App would not have a login interface, First question would it be accepted in App review, Or should i change something, Second questions how would the reviews would test my Facebook App.

Comment: The documentation for the app review process has a sub-chapter explicitly titled “Server-to-Server Apps” …

Comment: @misorude I have gone through it, But was not able to find answers to these questions.

Comment: Whether they will approve your app’s use of the permissions and features, depends on whether you are using them as you are supposed to, not on whether your app has a “login interface”. And what info they want from you for app review, is explicitly explained in there.

Comment: @misorude i am also referring to this link, 
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/review/login-permissions
In this link listed are the features i want to use and in the very first line it is written that "The following permissions require approval through the App Review process. Once approved, you can use Facebook Login to ask Users to grant your app any approved permissions."

Comment: And …? Not seeing your point here. That you then _can_ ask users for these permissions via Facebook Login, doesn’t mean that you _have to_ implement a public-facing login …

Comment: @misorude what i understand is that the features under this heading "login-permissions" implied that everything that is listed  below requires login permission when App is approved. May be i am wrong

Comment: @misorude, In short, i wanted to be sure that having these features enabled in my   App Facebook don't require me to have login interface specifically

Comment: It doesn’t. Of course you will want to grant certain permissions even to a server-to-server app, because without any it will hardly be able to do anything. But that does not mean that you have to implement a public-facing login, if only the app admin generates an access token including the necessary permissions for example via Graph API Explorer, that is perfectly fine for this type of use case.

Comment: @DaniyalSyed Could you submit the screencast? Should I show my code using the token and permission if I want to scrape some facebook page?

Comment: @JulianaRivera I was successful in getting the app approved because i had to turn of every option from Facebook login app, Which was causing issue, In screencast you just have to show how you are using the data,

Comment: @JulianaRivera and what permissions are you using for your App? The screen cast also depends on that

Comment: @DaniyalSyed I'm using Page Public Content Access and my application is a server to server. I want to retrieve number of comments, likes and so on from public pages.

Comment: @JulianaRivera then in screencast you just have to show how you are using that data which you are collecting,